# PHP Splitting an Array into two arrays - keys array and values array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there an easy way to split an array into two arrays, one consisting of all the keys and the other  consisting of all the values? This would be a reverse to the action of array_combine. Is there an inbuilt function for doing such a task? 
Let's use an example array:

```
$array = array('Tiger' => 'Forest', 'Hippo' => 'River', 'Bird' => 'Sky');
```

Is there a function that will split the above array into:

```
$array_keys = array('Tiger', 'Hippo', 'Bird');
$array_values = array('Forest', 'River', 'Sky');
```

Comment: Looked up the functions, used them and they work. So all the others are correct. I guess, I will be spending time with the PHP manual or any reference book. Thanks VERY MUCH to you all.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are two functions called  [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
$array_values = array_values($array);
```

Comment: But will it be absolutely the same order between the keys and values after they are separated? For any source array?

Comment: I believe so. For array_values the php documentation explicitly states '*array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically*'. As of 28/12/2017 I did not see such an explicit statement for array_keys. However, in the user contributed notes following the help text on the php website, a use of array_keys twice to get the position of an element (contributed by *vesely at tana dot it*) implies that array_keys returns key element in a similar way to array_values.

Answer (score 9):

There are two functions actually:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);
```

You can also do the exact opposite:

```
$array = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Answer (score 4):

use [array_keys](http://at.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_values](http://at.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough, the functions you're looking for are called `array_keys()` and `array_values()`.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$vals = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no built-in inverse of array_combine. There is also no way to define one, since array_combine expects multiple parameters and we can't return multiple values from a function.

We can construct an alternative to array_combine which takes a single argument: the array of keys and the array of values wrapped up together in another array. This transformation is called "uncurrying" and is performed by the "call_user_func_array" function:

```
$array_comb  = function($arr) { return call_user_func_array('array_combine', $arr); };
```

This alternative function does have an inverse:

```
$array_split = function($arr) { return array(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr)); };
```

If we define function composition:

```
$compose  = function($f, $g) {
    return function($x) use ($f, $g) { return $f($g($x)); };
};
```

Then the following functions are all (extensionally) equal, ie. they all return their argument unchanged:

```
$identity      = function($x) { return $x; };
$left_inverse  = $compose($array_split, $array_comb);  // Split then combine
$right_inverse = $compose($array_comb, $array_split);  // Combine then split
```

Note that they accept different argument types though:

- $identity will work on anything.
- $left_inverse will work on any array.
- $right_inverse will work on arrays-of-arrays, where the outer array contains 2 elements, both inner arrays are of equal length and the first inner array only contains integers and strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_split($data)
{
  $x = 0;//Counter to ensure accuracy
  $retArray[0] = array();//Array of Keys
  $retArray[1] = array();//Array of Values

  foreach($data as $key => $value)
  {
    $retArray[0][$x] = $key;
    $retArray[1][$x] = $value;
    $x++;
  }

  RETURN $retArray;
}

$data = array("key" => "value", "key2" => "value2");

$splitData = array_split($data);

//print_r($splitData[0]);//Output: Array ( [0] => key [1] => key2 ) 
//print_r($splitData[1]);//Output: Array ( [0] => value [1] => value2 ) 

print_r($splitData);
//Output:
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => key
            [1] => key2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value
            [1] => value2
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: You should explain your answer rather than just pasting the code